# The distribution of $\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$ when $X$ and $Y$ are independent Gaussian distributed

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I know that if it's a linear combination of gaussian distribution, then it is gaussian. But what about $\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$ when $X$, $Y$ are independent Centered Gaussian distributed?

Comment: A non-negative random variable cannot have Gaussian distribution.

Answer (score 2):

if $x$ and $y$ are Gaussian distributed with mean 0 and variance 1, the the required distribution is:
$$P(s)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} A e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2} \delta(s-\sqrt{x^2+y^2})~ dx ~ dy= \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{-r^2/2} \delta(s-r)~ r~ dr~ d\theta= A' se^{-s^2/2}$$

Comment: Does this mean $\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$ is also Gaussian distribution?

Comment: No it is maxwellian $f(z)=z e^{-z^2/2}$

Comment: Alternatively, $R\sim\chi_2$.

Answer (score 1):

If X and Y are independent jointly Centered Gaussian, the distribution of $\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$ is a [Rayleigh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution)

The easiest way to derive it is to do a polar coordinate change of variable's obtaining immediately (let's suppose X,Y standard Gaussian)

$$f_{XY}(x,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}$$

passing in polars you have

$$f_{R\Theta}(\rho,\theta)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\times \rho e^{-\frac{\rho^2}{2}}=f_{\Theta}(\theta)\times f_{R}(\rho)$$

Where

- $f_{\Theta}$ is the distribution of the angle, uniform in $[0;2\pi]$
- $f_{R}$ is the distribution of the radius, Rayleigh in $\rho \in [0;+\infty)$
- $R, \Theta$ independent

Nothing changes if X,Y are independent jointly gaussian $N(0;\sigma^2)$